# PDO MSSQL Fatal error: Invalid sql_display_size in

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm having problem on getting data from MSSQL Server. Here is my PDO function:

```
public function query_fetch($sql, $array='')
{
    if(!is_array($array)) $array = array($array);
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    if (!$query) {
        $this->error = $this->trow_error();
        $query->closeCursor();
        return false;
    } else {
        if($query->execute($array)) {
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $query->closeCursor();
            return (check_value($result)) ? $result : NULL;
        } else {
            $this->error = $this->trow_error($query);
            return false;
        }
    }

$query1 = 'SELECT * FROM Character';   
$query2 = 'SELECT Name,Something FROM Character';
```

When i type   `$query2` it's success. But on `$query1` I get following error:

> Fatal error: Invalid sql_display_size in C:....

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks related to binary data in the selected data. Does the Character table contain binary or varbinary data types ?

Answer (score 1):

Invalid sql_display_size

This error is common when you have you binary data type and its size is more than 4000.

Check your data type sizes  of your table.